# Question about a property about affine algebraic sets, specifically the proof of $V(\bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha})=\bigcap_{\alpha}V(S_{\alpha})$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, algebraic-geometry

I would like some help in understanding the proof of the theorem enclosed below. Specifically I would like to know how the second first equality of the proof lead to other ones.  Also I am not clear on what the indexing set $S_{\alpha}$ is suppose to be.  I am including the relevant definitions for completeness.   I did a quick search on the site, I know my question has to do with something call quantifier elimination in mathematical logic from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1650819/are-existentially-defined-subsets-of-affine-algebraic-sets-unions-of-a-finite-nu).  I don't have any background in mathematical logic.

Let $k$ denote an algebraically closed field.  Fix a positing integer $n$ and denote by $A$ the polynomial ring $A=k[X_{1},\ldots,X_{n}].$  Typically ideals of $A$ will be denoted by $a,b,\ldots.$  We call the set $\mathbb{A}^{n}=\{(x_{1},\ldots x_{n})\in k^{n}\}$ an affine $n$-space.  Members of points in affine $n$-space, and the function $P\mapsto x_{j}(P)$ gives the coordinates of the points.

To each subset $S$ of polynomials in $A$, associate the locus of common zeros, or zero locus of the members of $S:$

$V(S)=\{P\in \mathbb{A}^{n}| f(P)=0 \text{ for all } f\in S\}$

$V(S)$ is called an affine algebraic set in $\mathbb{A}^{n}$.  If $S$ is a finite set $\{f_{1},\dots,f_{n}\}$ of polynomials, then $V(\{f_{1},\dots,f_{n}\})$ is abbreviated as $V(f_{1},\dots,f_{n}).$ From the definition that $V(S)=\bigcap_{f\in S} V(f)$ for any subset $S$ of $A$.

Theorem:  Affine algebraic sets in $\mathbb{A}^{n}$ have the following properties:

$V(\bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha})=\bigcap_{\alpha}V(S_{\alpha})$ if the $S_{\alpha}$'s are arbitrary subsets of $A$.

Proof:

$V(\bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha})=\bigcap_{f\in {\bigcup_{\alpha}S_{\alpha}}}V(f)=\bigcap_{\alpha}\bigcap_{f\in S_{\alpha}}V(f)=\bigcap_{\alpha}V(S_{\alpha})$.

What I would like to know, from definition of $V(S)$, $V(\bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha})=\{P\in \mathbb{A}^{n}| f(P)=0 \text{ for all } f\in \bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha}\}$, in the subexpression $f\in \bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha}$, should not that mean $f\in S_{\alpha}$ for some $\alpha$? (not sure what the indexing set is suppose to be here) How does this lead to $\bigcap_{f\in {\bigcup_{\alpha}S_{\alpha}}}V(f)?$ Because in the next equality, we have $\bigcap_{\alpha}\bigcap_{f\in S_{\alpha}}V(f)$, Should there be a $\bigcup_{\alpha}$ instead of $\bigcap_{\alpha}?$  I understand that $\bigcap_{\alpha}V(S_{\alpha})$ to mean $V(S_{\alpha})=\{P\in \mathbb{A}^{n}| f(P)=0 \text{ for all } f\in \alpha\}$ (again, I am not sure I am not clear on what the indexing set is suppose to be).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From the definition we have that $V(S)=\bigcap_{f\in S}V(f)$ for any $S\subset A$. In particular, $V(\bigcup_\alpha S_\alpha)=\bigcap_{f\in \bigcup_\alpha S_\alpha}V(f)$. Indexing set is an arbitrary (fixed) set parametrizing a family of subsets $S_\alpha\subset A$. To say that $P\in \bigcap_{f\in \bigcup_\alpha S_\alpha}V(f)$ is equivalent to saying that $P\in V(f)$ for all $f\in \bigcup_\alpha S_\alpha$, equivalently, for all $\alpha$ and all $f\in S_\alpha$ we have $P\in V(f)$, equivalently, $P\in\bigcap_\alpha\bigcap_{f\in S_\alpha} V(S_\alpha)$.

Comment: I just saw your response now.  Thank you for replying. Can you explain how "for all $f\in \bigcup_\alpha S_\alpha$, equivalently, for all $\alpha$ and all $f\in S_\alpha.$",  My understanding of $f\in \bigcup_\alpha S_\alpha$ translates into "$\exists\alpha (\alpha\wedge f\in S_{\alpha}).$  I am not sure how having an universal quantifier before $f$ would affect the expression.  I mean, how does there exists at least one $\alpha$ get turn into for all $\alpha$?

Comment: @Seth: If something holds for every element of a union of sets, then it holds for every element of every individual set, and vice versa. What is your problem? Do you want to formally infer this statement from the axioms of ZFC? Then probably the tag of the question should be set-theory, not algebraic-geometry.

Comment: I thought it is something from the basic algebraic geometry that I am not seeing.  I have never seen justifications for how or why quantifiers get moved out of set builder notations.

Comment: @Seth: informally: Let's denote the index set by $I$. You want to show that for every $\alpha\in I$ every $f\in S_\alpha$ has some property $P(f)$. Take arbitrary $\beta\in I,g\in S_\beta$. Then $g$ is an element of the union of all $S_\alpha$, hence we have $P(g)$, and this is what we want.

Comment: don't $\forall f \in\bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha}$", means $\forall f \in\{x|\exists\alpha\in I \wedge x\in S_{\alpha}\}$, which means $\exists\alpha\in I, \forall f \in S_{\alpha}$.  I mean $\bigcup_{\alpha} S_{\alpha}$ in set builder notation as an index family of sets by itself involves an existential quantifier.  I am trying to see how that gets absorbed by "for all $f$".

Comment: @Seth: no, "for all $f$ in the union of $S_\alpha$" and "$\exists\alpha\in I, \forall f\in S_\alpha$" are different things. Consider the example $I=\{1,2\}$. Then the first sentence says "for all elements of $S_1$ _and_ all elements of $S_2$", while the second: "for all elements of $S_1$ _or_ all elements of $S_2$".

Comment: @Seth: you can write $\forall f\in\{x|\exists\alpha\in I\wedge x\in S_\alpha\} \colon P(f)$, if you want. But it is equivalent to $\forall\alpha\in I,\forall f\in S_\alpha \colon P(f)$. First statement implies second: take any $\alpha\in I$, then any $f\in S_\alpha$ belongs to the union, hence $P(f)$. Second implies first: take any $f$ in the union, then it belongs to $S_\alpha$ for some $\alpha$, hence $P(f)$.

Comment: I don't think I have seen this in how to prove type books.  Is this something in advanced symbolic logic?

Comment: @Seth: in Wikipedia it is called Universal generalization, if I am not mistaken. Probably in mathematical books it is considered as an obvious thing that does not need discussion.

Comment: I thought the use of existential quantifers doesn't imply the use of universal quantifers.   I mean at least for index family of sets.  I will look at Wikipedi.  Thank you for your detail responses.